# INSERT и SELECT массивов из таблицы PostgreSql используя Qt

Tags: массивы, qt, postgresql

Собираюсь писать клиентское приложение для `PostgreSql` базы с использованием `Qt`. Возможно ли будет получать и записывать в базу массивы с использованием `QSqlQuery`? Если да, то прошу небольшой пример. В гугле однозначного ответа на этот вопрос не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно возможно, чаще всего это происходит с помощью циклов. Пример SELECT с документации [QT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html).

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM artist");
int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("country");
while (query.next()) {
    QString country = query.value(fieldNo).toString();
    doSomething(country);
}
```

Пример с INSERT и prepare:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
query.exec();
```